# Using Views with two sql servers

Tags: database, drupal-views, webserver

I am trying to set up Views on my CiviCRM 4.7.10 (Drupal 7.42). My Drupal database is on one SQL server. And my CiviCRM database is on another SQL server.
Whenever I try to create a new view, I encounter the following message: 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'xxxxx'@'xxxxxx' for table 'civicrm_contact'
After looking intensively through the documentation, I cannot manage to find the right changes so that Views can connect to the correct SQL server. 
I have tried changing the file settings.php, but with no success.
Could someone kindly tell me what to do so that Views connects correctly to the SQL server where the CiviCRM is?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual:
1. If you have different database users for your CiviCRM and Drupal databases, then you need to grant SELECT access for the Drupal user to all the CiviCRM tables.